# How to create trigger MySQL in PHP MyAdmin

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a mysql table named `keywords` like this

```
id - route - keyword - keyword2
```

I need to take on each row insert the keyword and add it to the last column keyword2 in the same column.

I am trying this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_keyword BEFORE INSERT ON keywords
 ON keywords
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO keywords (keyword2) VALUES (NEW.keyword);
 END
```

PHP My Admin returns syntax error.

Please, some body could tell me what am I doing wrong. ?

Maybe is not possible add a trigger in the same table ?

Thanks in advance. Please somebody help me .... I am crazy about this..

Comment: Please read this tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/introduction-to-mysql-triggers--net-12226

Comment: Hi valicu2000. Thanks a lot. I will read it carefully...  :-)

Comment: Hi valicu2000. Just want to say thanks. The article help me a lot ..!  My trigger is working now..